# Script to parse fields

Tags: shell, text-processing

I need to parse a file & extract certain fields:

Sample file format :

```
"make":"honda","group":"xyz","model":"accord","year":"2007","miles":"67000"
"make":"honda","group":"abc","model":"civic","year":"2011","miles":"40000"
"make":"toyota","group":"abc","model":"camry","year":"2011","miles":"40000"
"make":"toyota","color":"black","group":"hgh","model":"camry","year":"2015","miles":"2000"
"make":"lincoln","color":"silver","group":"ugh","model":"MKZ","year":"2013","miles":"20000"
```

I need to extract fields under model & miles & write into a separate file .
From the above, I need an extract as below :

```
accord:67000
civic:40000
camry:40000
camry:2000
MKZ:20000
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Awk:

```
awk -F'[:,]' '{gsub(/"/,""); printf "%s:%s\n", $(NF-4),$NF}' file
accord:67000
civic:40000
camry:40000
camry:2000
MKZ:20000
```